# How can I prevent a new canvas backpack from fading its color over time?

Tags: clothing, lifespan, color

I liked a backpack, but in the online store, they put a picture saying the bag will fade its color over time (probably in less than a year).

Here is the picture:

[image: backpack]

So, I am wondering if it is possible to apply something (like for example hair spray) on the bag preventing this to happen?

Comment: I don't know of any spray or product that will prevent it from fading. As far as I know, it will fade from being in the sun. The more you can keep it indoors or shaded, the longer the color will last. There is a possibility you could have it dyed back to its original color when it does start to fade, but that might cost more than the original bag.

Comment: From the pictures & their statement, it sounds like it's *designed* to fade. It probably intentionally uses less colour-fast dyes to give that effect quickly. If you want one that doesn't fade, don't buy that one.

Comment: If it's a reconstruction of an historic item, you could probably find a cheaper one that's not designed to fade. And by the way, to my eye faded one looks way better :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the following:

- Salt:
  Add a tablespoon of salt to the wash, and the chloride will help our clothing pack a colorful punch when it comes out of the dryer. 
  Chloride found in salt actually helps to seal the color in backpacks, thus keeping it from fading.
- COLD WATER:
  Washing backpacks in cold water will not only help you cut down on your bills, but it will also help to keep your backpack colors from fading. Pair the cold water cycle with a color brightening detergent to boost your colors in the wash.
- VINEGAR
  If you add ½ cup of white vinegar to the rinse cycle, the liquid will freshen up your laundry and help colors maintain their intensity. Prior to a first washing, you can also soak dark backpacks for 30 minutes in water mixed with ½ cup of vinegar and 2 teaspoons of salt to help set the dyes.
- BAKING SODA:
  Baking soda can also be added to your laundry to help backpacks maintain their brightness. Add ½ cup of baking soda during the wash cycle to try it out.
- AIR DRYING:
  If you want to help your backpacks maintain their color after washing, you can let them hang to air dry. But remember to keep them out of the sun for best results, since exposure to the sun can fade backpacks even quicker than a spin cycle.

After all the other "pre-treatment", you can apply spray-on fabric protector. This will reduce fade and is washable.

Comment: +1 @Maneesh. In addition, after all the other "pre-treatment" you can apply spray-on fabric protector. Will reduce fade and is washable.

Comment: @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae Thank you brother, added this to answer

Comment: These are procedures for making dyes permanent with mordants. Great advice.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like the fade is intended, although it would be odd for someone to wait more than a couple of washes for that to happen.

I would look at finding the same color dye, or possibly one I liked better in the same color category and periodically dye it.

https://www.ritstudio.com/techniques/the-basics/washing-machine-top-loader/